# How to implement multi-threading for a recursive function

Tags: multithreading, recursion, clojure

Consider a simple 2-player game played as follows: An even number of coins is laid out in a row. Taking turns, each player removes the coin on one of the ends of the row. The object is to have the highest value in coins when all coins have been taken.

Player one finds the sum of all of the even-numbered coins, and all the odd-numbered coins. If the sum of the odd numbered coins is higher, player one takes the leftmost coin; otherwise he takes the rightmost.

Player two now has a choice, with an odd number of coins. Taking either the first coin or the last coin will result in a slightly different list of coins for player one. Player two uses the result of a recursive search to determine whether to pick the first or the last coin.

And I want to be able to somehow implement multi-threading on the `p2-helper` recursive function, just now sure how. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
(ns game.core
  (:gen-class))

; function that returns the vector of a string (split up by spaces)
(defn vector-from-string [s]
  (drop 1 (map read-string (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/trim-newline s) #" "))))

; function that returns the slurped string of a read-in file
(defn string-from-file [f]
  (slurp f))

; function that returns the sum of all the odd-indexed items in a vector
(defn sum-of-evens [v]
  (reduce + (take-nth 2 (rest v))))

; function that returns the sum of all the odd-indexed items in a vector
(defn sum-of-odds [v]
  (reduce + (take-nth 2 v)))

; function that returns the vector that is left after player one moves, and then the coin that player one took
(defn p1 [v]
  (if (> (sum-of-odds v) (sum-of-evens v))
    [(drop 1 v) (first v)]
    [(drop-last v) (last v)]))

; nearly identical to 'p1' but this function only returns the affected vector after player 1 has moved
(defn p2-p1 [v]
  (if (even? (count v))
    (if (> (sum-of-odds v) (sum-of-evens v))
      (drop 1 v)
      (drop-last v))
    (drop 0 v)))

; recursive search for player two
(defn p2-helper [v]
  (if (or (= (count v) 1) (= (count v) 0))
    (reduce + v)
    (max (+ (p2-helper (drop 1 (p2-p1 v))) (first (p2-p1 v))) (+ (p2-helper (drop-last (p2-p1 v))) (last (p2-p1 v))))))

; function that returns the vector that is left after player two moves, and then the coin that player two took
(defn p2 [v]
  (if (> (+ (p2-helper (drop 1 (p2-p1 v))) (first (p2-p1 v))) (+ (p2-helper (drop-last (p2-p1 v))) (last (p2-p1 v))))
    [(drop 1 v) (first v)]
    [(drop-last v) (last v)]))

; function to play the game out until no coins are left
(defn play-game [v]
  (def coins v)
  (def p1score 0)
  (def p2score 0)
  (while (not (empty? coins))
    (do
      (let [[new-vec score] (p1 coins)]
        (def coins new-vec)
        (def p1score (+ p1score score)))
      (let [[new-vec score] (p2 coins)]
        (def coins new-vec)
        (def p2score (+ p2score score)))))
  (println "player 1 score:" p1score)
  (println "player 2 score:" p2score))

; main
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [v (vector-from-string (string-from-file "10.txt")) ]
    (play-game v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An initial approach would be to just add `@(future (p2-helpet ...` around each recursive call. this will likely run too many threads and run slower.

a second approach might be to change the helpers to put work on a task queue and make some threads to process them. this will be better, though still might be slower.

I'd continue improving it by unrolling the recursion with a call to `trampoline` to stop it blowing the stack. then try just making the top level parallel, or just the two top levels.